# sprockets and performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I've noticed that many pages with heavy javascript load certain files at the end so pages load faster, can sprockets help me do this in Rails 3? If not, what methods can I use to help performance when using scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to consider here - first, the browser. Most modern browsers can asynchronously load resources, so the old trick of putting javascript at the end of the html isn't as necessary as it once was. Have a read through this article on asynce at css-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/

Next, the point of the asset pipeline is to concatenate, minify and compress all the javascript and css into two files, one 'application.js' and one 'application.css'. 
This serves to reduce HTTP requests and means that only the first page load will take 
The logic is, that with proper caching, the first load will take longer to get the monster files, but once they've been downloaded, the user has the js and stylesheets cached on their machine.
Have a read through the asset pipeline guide for more information about its use and benefits: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html